# Find the expected number of dinners it takes in order for everyone to have paid at least once

Tags: probability

> A group of n friends often go out for dinner together. At their dinners, they play “creditcard roulette” to decide who pays the bill. This means that at each dinner, one person is chosen uniformly at random to pay the entire bill.
>
> (a) Find the probability that in $k$ dinners, no one will have to pay the bill more than once.
>
> (b) Find the expected number of dinners it takes in order for everyone to have paid at least once (you can leave your answer as a finite sum of simple-looking terms).
>
> (c) Alice and Bob are two of the friends. Find the covariance between how many times Alice pays and how many times Bob pays in k dinners (simplify fully).

What i did so far:

a) Solve the opposite problem. The probability, that in $k$ trial one people paid $k$ times is $(\frac{1}{n})^k=> $ probability of not paing is P(X=0)=$1- (\frac{1}{n})^k$ . $P(X=1)= \binom k 1 \frac1n (1-\frac1n)^{k-1} =>$ Prob. for one person to pay at most 1 time is $P(X \le 1)=P(X=0)+P(X=1)$

b) Expected number of trials for one person to pay at least once is 1. Is the distribution Binom(n, 1/n)?

c) Here the quantity of how many times each person paid can be represented as $Multi(k,(\frac1n,\frac1n,\frac1n...)$, therefore the covariance is -$\frac{k}{n^2}$

Can you give me some hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part a)
Suppose there are k dinners that are required such that each of the n people pay for it just once. with $k\le n$ the the probability of such an event is  - there are n ways to choose the one to pay for the first gift, there are (n-1) ways to pay for the second dinner and goes until (n-k+1) ways to pay for the kth dinner.

$$ n.(n-1)...(n-k+1)\frac{1}{n^k} = \frac{n!}{(n-k)!.n^k}$$

For k>n  the probability can be simplified to 0.

For part b), It is the alternating sum of (k dinners are required for everyone to have paid once ) (2k dinners are required for everyone to have paid twice)+...

In other words, the expected number of dinners such that each of the n guests paid atleast once is

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} (-1)^i. (ki).\frac{n!^i}{(n-k)!^in^{ik}}$$

For part a) if n=3 and k =2 , the probability reduces to $\frac{2}{3}$

Answer (score 1):

For part (a):

You've calculated the probability that any given person pays at most once. Since the question asks for the probability that *every* person pays at most once, is there an easy way to combine these probabilities? Note that they aren't independent.

Alternatively, is there a direct way to count the situations in which every person pays at most once? Consider extreme cases, e.g., $k=1,2$ and $k>n$, then try $k=n$ and $k=n-1$. See if you can generalize.

Comment: I am sorry, but It is hard for me to edit from phone, so I will write it like that. If k<n
, for exampe, n=n k=n-1 Probability that eveyone paid at most once is n((1/n)(1/n-1)...(1/n-k+1)). If k>n then probability is 0, for example, if n=2, k=3 then first person pays for first, second for second and somebody must pay second time for third. If k=n then (1/n)(1/n-1)...(1/n-k+1)

Comment: I'm not sure your formula is right for the k<n case. Let's say k=2, n=3. Your formula gives 3(1/3)(1/2) = 1/2. But we can count the cases explicitly. Let the three people be A, B, C. The nine possibilities are AA, AB, AC, BA, BB, BC, CA, CB, CC. In six of them (AB, AC, BA, BC, CA, CB) no one paid more than once. So the probability should be 6/9 = 2/3, not 1/2.